# I want a <div> to be in the exact center; don't know how to deal with bottom and right margin

Tags: html, css

I made a French flag and want this to keep the same margin to the edge of browser. The ratio of the container might change. The picture below show what I've done.

[image]

Only top and left margins work as I want. I intended `margin: 0 0;` to keep the gaps always by 0; but the right and bottom ones do not work.

[image]

So can I set all the margins equally? Here is the whole code.

```css
#wrap {
  /*I've tried to change this part*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  margin: 0 0;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
#wrap div {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#wrap div:first-child {
  margin-right: 33.3333333333%;
  background: #003153;
}
#wrap div:first-child + div {
  background: #cc3333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just use `margin: 0 auto` on the wrapper div which centers the div element horizontally.

Comment: @KarelG OP has made the container `position: absolute` -- changing the margin by itself won't be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers sets margin for body by default,which was causing the issue.
Set `margin:0` for `body`
Change the width in `#wrap` to 100%

```
body
        {
            margin:0;
        }

 #wrap{ 
                    position: absolute;
                    width:100%;
                    height:90%;
                    /*height: 500px;*/
                    margin: 0 0;
                    border:4px solid #000;}
```

Comment: a small gap still exists on the left side; which pushes the `<div>` to the right.

Comment: @YeongchanJeon Lemme check

Comment: ya..browsers set default margin by default

Answer (score 0):

For your wrap use `left: 5%;`

also just use `margin: 0;` not `margin: 0 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this...

Change the HTML to..

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Then style the blocks like so..

```
.blue {
   background: #003153;
 }

.red {
   background: #cc3333;
 }

.white {
   background: #FFF;
 }
```

For the containers use...

```
 #wrap {
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    font-size: 0; /* necessary to remove space between divs */
  }

  #wrap div {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/bgxLbZ)

```css
#wrap {
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  font-size: 0;
  /* necessary to remove space between divs */
}
#wrap div {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue {
  background: #003153;
}
.red {
  background: #cc3333;
}
.white {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```